# How to write UPDATE SQL with Table alias in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, alias

I have a very basic `UPDATE SQL` -

```
UPDATE HOLD_TABLE Q SET Q.TITLE = 'TEST' WHERE Q.ID = 101;
```

This query runs fine in `Oracle`, `Derby`, `MySQL` - but it *fails in SQL server 2008* 
with following error:

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1  Incorrect syntax near 'Q'."

If I remove all occurrences of the alias, "Q" from SQL then it works.

But I need to use the alias.

Comment: Why do you need to use an alias? It doesn't seem like you need it.

Comment: Yes - from the programming perspective I do not need it. But I have an existing/old library which generates all kind of DML SQLs with table aliases. The library has lot of classes with a kind of complex logic. Now getting rid of table-aliases in the library is more work than tweaking the existing logic to work for MSSQL. Also when multiple tables are involved, I do need to have table-alias.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

The syntax for using an alias in an update statement on SQL Server is as follows:

```
UPDATE Q
SET Q.TITLE = 'TEST'
FROM HOLD_TABLE Q
WHERE Q.ID = 101;
```

The alias should not be necessary here though.

Comment: Yes !!!  It works.  Thanks for the quick response. By any chance do you know why MSSQL server supports such unconventional syntax for update?

Comment: Mark Byers - Great Answer!! This syntax allows me to add a commented out Select statement, which allows me to test the update by doing the select first (highlight from the select down and execute): `SET Q.TITLE = 'TEST' -- SELECT *`

Comment: Nice. This makes it easier to use intellisense in the where clause.

Comment: That's not an alias. That's just the fully qualified 'table.column' name :-/

Comment: @ScottWelker - `HOLD_TABLE` is the table. `Q` is the alias. `TITLE` is the column.

Comment: Right @galdin. Don't know what I was thinking :(

Comment: Aliases are necesarry if you need to add table joins before where clause, otherwise not

Answer (score 21):

You can always take the [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), (Common Tabular Expression), approach.

```
;WITH updateCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, TITLE 
    FROM HOLD_TABLE
    WHERE ID = 101
)

UPDATE updateCTE
SET TITLE = 'TEST';
```

Comment: Yes - it also works. But for a JDBC/Java program this is a kind of complex syntax. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have written needs to be modified. I feel that there is no need of using alias keyword in your query.

**Without Alias keyword:**

```
    UPDATE HOLD_TABLE 
    SET TITLE='TEST'
    WHERE ID=101;
```

**With Alias keyword:** [(CTE approach)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

```
    WITH HOLD_TABLE1 AS 
    (SELECT * FROM HOLD_TABLE)
    UPDATE HOLD_TABLE1 
    SET TITLE='TEST'
    WHERE ID=101;
```