# How to improve the speed of this SQL update query?

Tags: sql, performance

Sorry, this is my first time using this forum. Apparently people can edit my post which although helpful, has taken some information out.
I will try to make it more understandable.

I am using SQL Compact 3.5 as a local database.
The program is written in VB.NET.

The problem is with querying one of my tables that is taking too long.

The player table has, among other things, `id`, `skill`, `school`, `weight`, `starter`.

- `id` is the player's id
- `skill` is the player's skill level
- `school` is a foreign key pointing to the id of the school table
- `weight` is one of 14 different numbers

What I am trying to do is set the `starter` value = 'true' for the player with the highest skill at a given weight for a given school.
So if there are 100 players at a school, there will be 14 starters, one for each weight.

The player table has 170,000 players, each having 1 of 14 different weights, and each belongs to 1 of 4500 schools.

Someone commented below and showed this statement which appears to be on the right track. I am a novice and have not gotten it implemented quite yet.

```
  "UPDATE p " &
  "SET starter = 'TRUE' " &
  "FROM player p" &
  "JOIN (" &
  "SELECT DISTINCT school, weight, MAX(skill) AS MaxSkill " &
  "FROM player " &
  "GROUP BY school, weight" &
  ") q ON q.school = p.school AND q.weight = p.weight AND q.MaxSkill =
   p.skill"
```

Comment: Is weight a range or a number? Ie should only weight 14 be grouped with other 14 or also with for example 13-15?

Comment: Simple answer - don't do it one school/weight at a time.

Comment: Show an example of what you want as output, not really clear from your question..

Comment: You have indexes on your tables right?  http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-index.php   if not, this may help speed it up significantly.  The select part at least.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing a group-by-group, row-by-row approach, this update query does it all at once:

First, it gathers the highest `skill` for each `school` / `weight` combination.

It then joins that to the `player` that has the matching `school` / `weight` / `skill` combination, and then sets that `player` to the starter.

```
UPDATE p
SET starter = 'TRUE'
FROM player p 
JOIN (
    SELECT school, weight, MAX(skill) AS MaxSkill
    FROM player
    GROUP BY school, weight
) maxResults 
    ON maxResults.school = p.school 
    AND maxResults.weight = p.weight 
    AND maxResults.MaxSkill = p.skill
```

However, in the case of a tie in skill, all players with the highest skill would be set to a starter...

Answer (score 1):

There's some minor confusion over the use of `weight`, as I'm assuming you you're not doing this on a per-unit basis.  You may want to extract out ranges to another table, then use the id's there instead of a numeric weight.

In any case, here's a query that should work for all RDBMSs

```
UPDATE player a SET starter = TRUE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                  FROM player b
                  WHERE b.school = a.school
                  AND b.weight = a.weight
                  AND b.skill > a.skill)
```

The inner query should return `null` (thus setting `starter` true) if:

1. There are no other players at the school
2. There are no players at the same school, in the same weight class
3. There are no players with a higher skill level, for the same school and weight class

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to set the alias inside of the update. How do I do this for SQL compact server 3.5? I found a question similar, but I was not able to figure it out off of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981481/how-to-write-update-sql-with-table-alias-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @Meowbits - You need to remove the `as`, which apparently are not agnostic

Comment: I was told that the compact version of SQL does not support a lot of features... apparently that is why I am getting errors. Thanks for the help though, appreciate it!