# Syntax error in SQL query

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am having problems implementing this query in vb.net.
The error message that I am getting is with the "as" in the first line.
This is a local sql compact database 3.5

```
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE player as a " &
                            "SET starter = 'TRUE' " &
                            "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1' " &
                            "FROM player AS b " &
                            "WHERE(b.school = a.school) " &
                            "AND b.weight = a.weight " &
                            "AND b.skill > a.skill)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Error message - http://i40.tinypic.com/34gms5z.png

```
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE a " &
                "SET starter = 'TRUE' " &
                "FROM player a " &
                "LEFT JOIN player b " &
                "ON a.school = b.school " &
                "AND a.weight = b.weight " &
                "AND b.skill > a.skill " &
                "WHERE b.school is NULL"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Error message - http://i40.tinypic.com/106kn86.png

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your SQL ... what are you trying to do with that query?  UPDATE: I see now, you're trying to make everyone a starter, than whom there's no more skilled player of the same weight at the same school

Comment: Related question (but not a duplicate): [How to improve the speed of this SQL update query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847599/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-this-sql-update-query).

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
UPDATE player
SET starter = 'TRUE' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM player b 
    WHERE b.school = player.school
    AND b.weight = player.weight 
    AND b.skill > player.skill
)
```

**Edited to add:**

This will probably run faster if you create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX player_school_weight ON player (school, weight, skill)
```

Comment: YES!, this appears to be working. However it is pretty slow. If I made it a stored procedure would it be much faster you think?

Comment: No, writting it as a Stored procedure would NOT make it MUCH faster. The only speeding would be given because the query would be compiled beforehand and won't be needed to recompile it on each run. Diego's way may be faster, if you get it to run :) Otherwise, you'd have to check your indexes.

Comment: This is the correct answer. SQL Server Compact is VERY different from SQL Server, and does not support `left outer join` or table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want this:

```
UPDATE pl 
SET 
    starter = 'True'
FROM 
    [Player] pl
LEFT JOIN 
    [Player] pl2 ON (pl.[School] = pl2.[School])
    AND 
    (pl.[Weight] = pl2.[Weight])
    AND 
    (pl2.[Skill] > pl.[Skill])
WHERE pl2.[School] IS NULL
```

Comment: I get an error with this one too, same as above, error at "FROM" :/

Comment: There was a small typo (missing close bracket). It is now fixed.

Comment: SQL Server Compact is VERY different from SQL Server, and does not support `left outer join` or table aliases.