# Update from aggregate in same table if aggregate value wrong - SQL Server/Oracle/Firebird

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, firebird

I have a table with grouped tasks:

- `tt_plan_task_id` is the id
- records with `tt_plantype=1` represent 'groups'
- tasks in/under a group have a `tt_group_id` pointing to the `tt_plan_task_id`
- there are tasks that don't belong to a group (`tt_group_id` is null)
- groups nest multiple levels

I need to fix (update) the `tt_fromdate` field values for the group records if they do not match the `min(tt_fromdate)` from the underlying tasks (they always have a value).

To fix them all I could do

```
update tt_plan_task g
set tt_fromdate=
 (select min(t.tt_fromdate) from tt_plan_task t
  where (t.tt_group_id=g.tt_plan_task_id))
where (g.tt_plantype=1)
```

This statement avoids the UPDATE FROM syntax that I see in many (SQL server) answers - Firebird does not support that.

There are 2 complications

1. I want to do the update only if `g.tt_fromdate <> min(t.tt_fromdate)`, so I would have to add a reference to `min(tt_fromdate)` to the outer where.
   I tried using an alias for the aggregate and referencing that but that got me nowhere (syntax errors)
2. SQL Server does not like the table alias in the update, but [solutions like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981481/how-to-write-update-sql-with-table-alias-in-sql-server-2008) use the UPDATE FROM syntax again ;-( How do I work around that then?

How do I tie 1. and 2. into my update statement so that it works?
As noted in the title, this needs to execute in SQL Server, Oracle, and Firebird

Note: Since groups can contain groups, the update should ideally be executed 'from the bottom up', i.e. deepest groups first.
But since this is just a rough correction for a corrupt database, doing one 'lineair' pass over all groups is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around SQL Server's non-standard way for update table aliases, simply don't use any.

As to using the aggregate result in both the SET clause and the WHERE clause, I suppose the only way all DBMS work with, is to write the aggregation query twice.

```
update tt_plan_task
set tt_fromdate =
(
  select min(t.tt_fromdate) 
  from tt_plan_task t
  where t.tt_group_id = tt_plan_task.tt_plan_task_id
)
where (tt_plantype=1)
and 
(
  tt_fromdate <>
  (
    select min(t.tt_fromdate) 
    from tt_plan_task t
    where t.tt_group_id = tt_plan_task.tt_plan_task_id
  )
);
```

Comment: Ah, the trick is not using the alias for **one** table reference ;-)