# Update statement works with temp table but not with table valued variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery, rdl

I defined this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #stagingtable
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    typeflag int default 0,
    resourcetype varchar(25),
    resource varchar(40),
    est int,
    planned int,
    actual int
)

And then I am looking for places where the resourcetype is not the same as the resourcetype in the previous row, so I wrote the following UPDATE:

UPDATE #stagingtable
SET typeflag = 1 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM #stagingtable
)
OR resourcetype <> (
    SELECT resourcetype
    FROM #stagingtable rt2
    WHERE rt2.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) 
        FROM #stagingtable rt3
        WHERE rt3.id < #stagingtable.id
    )
)
```

This worked perfectly. However, the environment I am in won't let me use temp tables (RDL!). So I changed my table to a table-valued variable:

```
DECLARE @stagingtable TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    typeflag int default 0,
    resourcetype varchar(25),
    resource varchar(40),
    est int,
    planned int,
    actual int
)

But the following code doesn't work. 

UPDATE @stagingtable
SET typeflag = 1 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM @stagingtable
)
OR resourcetype <> (
    SELECT resourcetype
    FROM @stagingtable rt2
    WHERE rt2.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) 
        FROM @stagingtable rt3
        WHERE rt3.id < @stagingtable.id
    )
)
```

I get the message:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 431 Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@stagingtable".

Is there a way to change the update statement so it works?

Comment: @variables are local to the batch. i assume you have a GO command somewhere or are running this elsewhere that is accessible. You can try @@variable but if you are trying to keep this variable around for any time it isn't the way to go. why not just use a #temp?

Answer (score 5):

Your query is almost fine. You only need to reference the table variable by the alias you gave it, on this last row:

> `WHERE rt3.id < @stagingtable.id`

```
DECLARE @stagingtable TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    typeflag int default 0,
    resourcetype varchar(25),
    resource varchar(40),
    est int,
    planned int,
    actual int
)


UPDATE @stagingtable
SET typeflag = 1 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM @stagingtable
)
OR resourcetype <> (
    SELECT resourcetype
    FROM @stagingtable rt2
    WHERE rt2.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) 
        FROM @stagingtable rt3
        WHERE rt3.id < rt2.id
    )
)
```

Comment: nice catch on the alias

Comment: I don't think this works because rt2.id is not the same as stagingtable.id

Comment: @GeoffSnowman what do you need to do there? the main table you cannot access like that as a simple variable, it is still a table, you will need a join to get the rows from it...

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I just checked this by running the query and the rt3.id<rt2.id syntax does produce the wrong answers. With this approach, typeflag is not set for any row other than the first row. With the query below, typeflag is set for any row where resourcetype is not the same as resourcetype in the previous row.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, anyway. :)

Comment: You should mark your answer as the right answer if anyone ever has the same issue.

Comment: You can't accept your own answer until the question has been up for a while.  Hour or two, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with the correct syntax, which is to add square brackets around the variable name:

```
UPDATE @stagingtable
SET typeflag = 1 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM @stagingtable
)
OR resourcetype <> (
    SELECT resourcetype
    FROM @stagingtable rt2
    WHERE rt2.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) 
        FROM @stagingtable rt3
        WHERE rt3.id < [@stagingtable].id
    )
)
```

Comment: Use `update ... from` so you can alias the outermost table.  As now, it's hard to read this and tell what's going on, and you're going to confuse someone later.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981481/how-to-write-update-sql-with-table-alias-in-sql-server-2008)