# alias in update SQL query is not working

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE Q
SET Q.FirstName="ram"
FROM Person Q
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near ".": syntax error)

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should tag your RDBMS, but try `'` instead of `"`

Comment: This thread gives query


UPDATE Q
SET Q.TITLE = 'TEST'
FROM HOLD_TABLE Q
WHERE Q.ID = 101;

How come it is not working for me?

Comment: @AAjit , you saw the thread, and it's to solve a problem for Sql server. Is you RDBMS sql server?

Comment: I am currently learning SQL from w3schools and creating tables on it. After searching a bit, they are using RDBMS but not sure which database system it is?

Answer (score 0):

You use from clause only if you update your table with data from other table. If not just:

```
UPDATE Person
   SET FirstName='ram'
```

Comment: This should run, but ideally there would be a `WHERE` clause to make sure the update doesn't rename everyone to `ram`.

Comment: It's common knowledge that this day and age everyone is ram, @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Here is thread which gives syntax for updating table with alias.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981481/how-to-write-update-sql-with-table-alias-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: This thread gives query


UPDATE Q
SET Q.TITLE = 'TEST'
FROM HOLD_TABLE Q
WHERE Q.ID = 101;

How come it is not working for me?

Comment: @AAjit That syntax is correct for SQL Server.  If you're getting an error on w3schools, just ignore it.  W3schools can be good, but doesn't have every compatibility of the real thing.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will test this with real databases.