# SQL Server: how to use alias in update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm wondering about the following query :

```
   UPDATE statisticsTable
   SET Value = (select count(*) 
                FROM OtherTable o
                WHERE o.UserId = UserId ) <-- this is the part that concerns me
   WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

How does SQL Server know that the second "UserId" field comes from `statisticsTable` and not from `OtherTable` ?
Why can't I give an alias to statisticstable like 'stat' to clarify where I want to get that UserId ? Or is there a way?

Comment: Is this working correctly? I usually do something like `WHERE o.UserId = statisticsTable.UserId` to be sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981481/how-to-write-update-sql-with-table-alias-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Cant you have `UPDATE statisticsTable as s`

and then have `WHERE o.UserID = s.UserId` in your subquery? I haven't tested this though. I've never had an UPDATE where a subquery has been neccessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQL Server supports updates using joins.
This means you can write your query like this:

```
UPDATE s
SET Value = d.NumOfRows
FROM statisticsTable s
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) As NumOfRows
     FROM OtherTable
     GROUP BY UserId
) d ON s.UserId = d.UserId
WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: This is something I have never seen before. Thanks!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: I marked you as the answer and upvoted it to show appreciation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE s
   SET Value = x.cnt
from statisticsTable s
 outer apply (select count(*) as cnt
                FROM OtherTable o
                WHERE o.UserId = s.UserId ) x
WHERE s.id in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alias for the table you are updating is not allowed but you can use the table name in the normal way:

```
UPDATE statisticsTable
SET Value = (select count(*) 
            FROM OtherTable o
            WHERE o.UserId = statisticsTable.UserId ) 
WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second "UserId" field comes from statisticsTable rather from OtherTable because the SQL server will first look for the "UserId" column within the statisticsTable. If "UserId" column exists in the statisticsTable, it will be used in the condition o.UserId = UserId. However, if there's no "UserId" column in the statisticsTable, SQL Server will then look for it in the OtherTable.

You can write the query using an alias to statisticsTable like 'stat'.

```
UPDATE stat
SET Value = (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OtherTable o
WHERE o.UserId = stat.UserId
)
FROM statisticsTable stat
WHERE stat.id IN (1,2,3);
```