# What is the 't' mean at end of the subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have following code used for query data by rows and start point:

```
SELECT InquiryId
FROM (select InquiryId,  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by InquiryId) as Seq 
from [InquiryTable] WITH(NOLOCK)
where InquiryId >= 100 and InquiryId <= 200)t
where Seq Between 1 and 20
```

What is character 't' means at the end of the forth row in SQL server?

Thanks

Comment: `t` is an alias for the sub-query. it can be anything other than a reserved keyword

Comment: I can't find a canonical Q&A for SQL Server aliases, but this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981481/how-to-write-update-sql-with-table-alias-in-sql-server-2008 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a helpful visual showing how `t` is an alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
```

Replace `table` with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM table) t
```

Answer (score 5):

It is an alias for your subquery. Improved indentation helps you to understand better:

```
SELECT InquiryId
FROM (select InquiryId,  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by InquiryId) as Seq 
      from [InquiryTable] WITH(NOLOCK)
      where InquiryId >= 100 
        and InquiryId <= 200
     ) AS t
where Seq Between 1 and 20
```

Answer (score -1):

doesn't mean matter, you are `renaming the table in the subquery as t`, but in from to rename you mustn't use as, but you must use directly the name in the table, and you can require the columns of the table or the subquery in you case using `t.col`

Comment: The subquery is named not any table in it.

Comment: I have corrected, however it works with subquery and with table

Comment: Perhaps a language issue? Still, I do not see any significant changes in your answer.